# String DependencyProperty to Nullable

Tags: c#, dependency-properties

I want to make a string `DependencyProperty` which can handle assigning to a nullable number value (like the textbox `TextProperty` does).

I basically copied the decompiled code from `TextBox` and changed it for the `DependencyProperty` I was creating.

```
[DefaultValue(null)]
//[DefaultValue(string.Empty)]
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.Text)]
public string Number
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(NumberProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NumberProperty, value); }
} 

public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Number", // Property name
                typeof(string), // Property type
                typeof(NumberControl), // Property owner 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( // Property metadata
                        null, // default value 
                        //string.Empty, // default value
                        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | // Flags 
                            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                        OnNumberPropertyChanged,    // property changed callback 
                        CoerceText,
                        true, // IsAnimationProhibited
                        UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged   // DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger
                        ));
private static object CoerceText(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    var sv = value as string;
    if (sv == String.Empty) return null;
    return value;
    //if( value == null) return string.Empty;
}

private static void OnNumberPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (NumberControl) d;
    if (tb.Number != tb.Text)
    {
        tb.Text = tb.Number;
    }
}
```

However when binding this property to a decimal? this is the exception which occurs

> System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=DecimalProperty;   DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=58431997); target element is 'NumberControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Number' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
>   at System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
>   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
>   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'

**Note**: I tried leaving the default string.empty behaviour which didn't work, and the code I've provided tries null which also doesn't work

Is there some way that `TextBox.Text` has specified some other default converter?

Comment: Can you add the binding of your property to your question please?

Comment: The Property it was bound to was a decimal? that implemented OnPropertyChanged() but could be any nullable struct e.g., int?, decimal?, double?, ect... Nothing special. I don't think it needs the actual property now that I've figured out what needed doing to it.

Comment: Jop I already saw and voted your answer. Glad you found the answer and shared it with us ;)

Comment: Cool. I thought it must have been, but thought I'd check first.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Answer**

You need to set the `DependancyProperty` directly to `null` with in the `PropertyChangedCallback` method specified for that `DependancyProperty` so that it doesn't use the default converter.

So in my case the `OnNumberPropertyChanged` method which is being used as the `PropertyChangedCallback` in the `DependancyProperty` needed to call

```
tb.SetValue(NumberProperty, null);
```

**Long Answer**

Damn I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624915/when-do-default-converters-kick-in) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625068/1462615) after posting my question, that question wasn't really phrased in a way that my searching came up with until I'd posted "default converter" at the end of my question.

The way I got it working was to manually set the `DependancyProperty` value to `null` at the appropriate time with the code:

```
    if (tb.Number == null)
    {
        tb.SetValue(NumberProperty, null);
    }
```

So the full OnNumberPropertyChanged method is:

```
    /// <summary> 
    /// Callback for changes to the Number property 
    /// </summary>
private static void OnNumberPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (NumberControl) d;
    if (tb.Number != tb.Text)
    {
        tb.Text = tb.Number;
    }
    if (tb.Number == null)
    {
        tb.SetValue(NumberProperty, null);
    }
}
```